# CreateTextRange and CreateRange methods not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, range

I Have written a simple script using createRange functions but it is not working in IE9.

```
function Select () {
            var srcObj = document.body;

            if (srcObj) {
                if (document.createRange) {     // all browsers, except IE before version 9
                    var rangeObj = document.createRange ();



                        rangeObj.selectNode (srcObj);
                        var sel=window.getSelection();
                       sel.removeAllRanges();
                       sel.addRange(rangeObj);


                }
                else {      // Internet Explorer before version 9
                    alert ("Your browser does not support this example!");
                }
            }
        }
```

I get the alert"Your browser does not support this example"

Comment: Is your HTML document in [Standards Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @RoToRa Great,This was the problem.Can you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE9 to support `createRange` the HTML document needs to be in [Standards Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx).